Karate-Gatling: Same code repository for both API Regression and API Performance Testing
This is related to Karate-Gatling setup.
Is it possible to use same GitHub Repository for having both API Regression and API Performance Testing ?
The reason I am asking this, for API Regression testing the Karate Framework needs TestRunner class while for Performance script Test Runner class is not needed. Now when I try to trigger Gatling script it triggers the Test Runner class and normal API tests run.
Is there any sample repo I can refer.

Refer to the "TODO" example - here is the link to the karate-1.5 branch, where you can use the Java DSL instead of Scala: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-todo/tree/karate-1.5
